# How to change UITableView frame and keep it?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have uitableview in my ViewController.ViewController is within navigationcontroller.When press button I'm changing uitableview frame on like this.

```
                 CGRect frame = tbleView.frame;
                 frame.size.height -= MapHeight;
                 frame.origin.y+=MapHeight;
                 tbleView.frame = frame;
```

Afterthat I push another ViewController to navigationcontroller and once go back my previous view "tbleView" frame automatically become initial view frame. I want to keep tbleView frame lastly assigned frame. How can I do that?

Comment: When you return from your viewController ,make a call to function to set frame of tableview. That would help you out.

Comment: Guessing there is a source code to reset the frame of the tableview. check viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, viewWillLayoutSubviews, viewDidLayoutSubviews, viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear methods in your ViewController.

Comment: @Joey I'm not use viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, viewWillLayoutSubviews, viewDidLayoutSubviews, viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear in my ViewController class.

Comment: @Hemal don't use the tableview you want to change the frame as a main view of ViewController, and turn off AutoLayout.

Comment: @Joey I turn off AutoLayout. Now it's working properly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any ideas how to reach it keeping auto layout?

Comment: @valdistt You can create reference for constrain and after that can change it directly on runtime.